# shopify_app gem webhooks not working on Heroku environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I use the shopify_app gem to add webhooks to my app.
They work as expected in my local environment, but when I use the app from my Heroku environment, nothing happens when I do actions that should trigger the webhooks, nor is there any errors or anything at all in the logs.

Any ideas for how I should proceed to determine what the error is?

Update c.f. Davids comment (thanks for the input David):

I've added a call to the API to see which webhooks are installed for the app, and I can see the webhooks have not been succesfully installed - I will dig into this.

My procfile for Heroku has the following content:

```
web: bundle exec rails s
webpacker: ruby bin/webpack-dev-server
inventoryworker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q urgent -c 3
clock: bundle exec clockwork scheduler.rb
```

The Heroku setup is as follows:

- one dyno for "web bundle exec rails s"
- one dyno for "clock bundle exec clockwork scheduler.rb"
- one dyno for "inventoryworker bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q urgent -c 3"
- one off dyno for "webpacker ruby bin/webpack-dev-server"

I am expecting the webhooks to be handled by inventoryworker?

Thanks,
-Louise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Davids hints I found out that the webhooks were not installed.
Looking at the logs during install I saw that the installation of webhooks works by adding a job to a queue - this queue name was not included in my configuration of starting sidekiq and for this reasonn webhooks were not installed.

Thanks,
-Louise

Answer (score 0):

Heroku logs. When you install the App, examine the logs. You'll see the webhooks be created or not. Ensure you setup Heroku correctly too. If you forgot a worker process, your webhook job won't run. Lots of little things to check.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer - I've updated my original question with additional details.
Can you see anything problematic with the Heroku setup?

Comment: Try using worker as a Proc. Not inventoryworker. That is not normal.